# How to compile lighttpd .tar file using cygwin to run executable file in Windows 10

Tags: linux, windows, webserver, lighttpd, mingw

I have downloaded [lighttpd tar](https://www.lighttpd.net/) file and I need it to compile it using cygwin for Windows 10 machine.

I did some extensive research on how to compile lighttpd files using cygwin in google but most of the articles are very old.

I need some guidance.

***UPDATE***

I know I need to use Mingw application to compile
LighTpd file to make it a Standalone application.

I tried looking up instruction online but I couldn't find any.

Comment: why you can not use the already available package ? https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/lighttpd.html

Comment: @matzeri do I run it under cygwin? I want it to create .exe file for the windows 10 to run the service in the background

Comment: Do you want to build a Cygwin program or a standalone program ? For a stand alone program you need to use Mingw not Cygwin

Comment: @matzeri Thank you for MinGW's advice!! I tried looking up how to create Lighttpd using MinGW. I have not to find instruction to perform the job. Can you help

Answer (score 1):

lighttpd can be built under Cygwin, or you can use the already-built lighttpd package in Cygwin.

The lighttpd executable can be run from the windows CMD prompt or as a Windows service.  Yes, the lighttpd executable links against cygwin.dll, but you do not have to be inside a bash shell to run the lighttpd executable.

tl;dr: just run the lighttpd executable

As for compiling lighttpd under cygwin yourself, have you tried reading the INSTALL file that is included with the lighttpd.tar?  (hint hint)

Comment: How can a Windows user download your already-built lighttpd package to use it separately from Cygwin bash shell? (I can't find a download link on https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/lighttpd.html , only a list of files).

Comment: @PeterCo you can use Cygwin `setup.exe` to install the *Cygwin lighttpd package*.  The *Cygwin lighttpd package* depends on cygwin.dll, so you need Cygwin installed.  The *Cygwin lighttpd package* is not packaged as a standalone installer.  (Did I repeat the phrase "*Cygwin lighttpd package*" sufficiently to get that point across?)  Once you have the set of files present on your machine, you do not need to execute lighttpd from within a bash shell.